# weird object returned by vector_indexing_suite

Tags: boost-python

I have a

```
std::vector<const T*>
```

that I return from a c++ function:

```
getallTs()
```

I have exposed the T class with:

```
class_<T,T*>
```

and the vector like so:

```
class_<std::vector<const T*> >("TsList")
  .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<const T*>,true>())
;
```

What does the NoProxy argument mean?

I expose the function like so:

```
  def("getallTs", getallTs,
      return_value_policy<return_by_value>{});
```

I observe a weird behaviour.

When I call from python

```
tlist = getallTs()
```

I get a TsList object.

```
len(tlist)
```

works.

```
tlist[<anycorrectindex>].<someattribute>
```

also works.

However, if I just

```
print(tlist[0])
```

and

```
print(tlist[100])
```

python prints

```
object T at <address>
```

This address is the same for all the Ts in tlist.

Also, I cannot iterate over Tlist with a python for loop.

```
for t in tlist:
```

doesn't work.

Any ideas what is wrong with the way I am exposing the vector and the function to python?

I understand the python objects that each wrap a c++ T hold a raw pointer to T.
These T instances exist throughout the process in a global table.

The c++ function retunrns a vector of pointers to those instances.
What does indexing_suite do with those?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing elements by index, the indexing suite defaults to providing a proxy to the element, as a means to provide reference semantics for mutable types that Python users will often expect with collections:

```python
val = c[i]
c[i].m()            # Mutates state, equivalent to `val.m()`
assert(val == c[i]) # Have same state.
val.m()
assert(val == c[i]) # Have same state.
```

In the above example, `val` is a proxy object that is aware of the container element.  When `NoProxy` is `true`, one gets value semantics when indexing, resulting in a copy on each index access.

```python
val = c[i]  # val is a copy.
c[i].m()    # Modify a copy of c[i].
assert(val == c[i]) # These have the same state because c[i] returns a new copy.
val.m()
assert(val != c[i]) # These do not have the same state.
```

When proxies are not used, the mutations to the elements will only persists when invoked on a reference to the element, such as during iteration:

```python
for val in c:
    val.m() # modification observed in c[#]
```

---

When invoking `print(c[i])`, a temporary proxy object is created and passed to `print`, and the lifetime of the proxy object ends upon returning from `print()`.  Hence, the memory and identification used by the temporary proxy object may be re-used.  This can result in elements appearing to have the same identification:

```python
id0 = id(c[0]) # id of the temporary proxy
id1 = id(c[1]) # id of another temporary proxy
assert(id0 ?? id1) # Non-deterministic if these will be the same.
assert(c[0] is not c[1]) # Guaranteed to not be the same.
```

On the other hand, during the lifetime of a proxy, other proxies to the same element will have identical identification, and proxies to different elements will have different identification:

```python
c0 = c[0]   # proxy to element 0.
c0_2 = c[0] # another proxy to element 0.
c1 = c[1]   # proxy to element 1
assert(c0 is c0_2)
assert(c0 is c[0])
assert(c0 is not c1)
```

---

In the situation where `T` has been exposed as being held by `T*`, iteration over `std::vector<const T*>` will fail in Python if there is no to-Python conversion for `const T*` to a Python object.  Exposing class `T` as being held by `T*` registers automatic to-Python and from-Python conversions for `T*`, not `const T*`.  When iterating over the collection in Python, references to elements are returned, resulting in a Python object failing to be constructed from a `const T*`.  On the other hand, when accessing elements via index, the resulting Python object is either a proxy or a copy, which can use the existing converters.  To resolve this, consider either:

- having `std::vector<>`'s element type be the same as `T`'s held type
- explicitly registering a `const T*` to-Python converter

Comment: Given that I exposed T with class_<T,T*>, how can I write a to_python_converter<const T*, Converter> ?
what would be in its convert function?

Comment: @MMM I show how to do that in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531728).  However, this type of pattern is a bit of code smell to me.  If this is not for Boost.Python academic purposes, then I would strongly consider examining alternative approaches.