# Boost.Python: inheret from C++ object in python: Cannot add to C++ base class list

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am trying to extend existing C++ objects in Python via inheritance.
I can do this successfully and run virtual methods overridden in Python. When I however, try to add the python object to a list of pointers of the C++ Base object type(the Base object the python class has overridden), I get a type error: 'Attempting to append an invalid type'

I am sure this error is due to there begin no 'implicitly_convertible' functionality from derived* to base*. In C++, this would be defined as so: implicitly_convertible<[Derived_from_base]*,Base*>();.
Is it possible to define this in python?

How can I achieve this?

Here is sample code reproducing this behaviour.

C++

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int f() = 0;
};
struct A {
    std::vector<Base*>& GetBaseList() { return m_base_List; }
    std::vector<Base*> m_base_List;
};
struct BaseWrap : Base, wrapper<Base> {
    int f() { return this->get_override("f")(); }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(sandbox)
{
    class_<BaseWrap, Base*, boost::noncopyable>("Base", no_init)
        .def("f", pure_virtual(&Base::f));

    class_<A, A*>("A", init<>())
        .add_property("baseList", make_function(&A::GetBaseList, return_internal_reference<>()));

    //implicitly_convertible<[Derived_from_base]*,Base*>();
    class_<std::vector<Base*>>("BaseList").def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<Base*>>());
}
```

Python
    from sandbox import *

```
class derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "test"
    def f(self):
        print("Hello Derived!")

d = derived()
d.f()          # Output: Hello Derived!

a = A()
a.baseList.append(d) # TypeError: Attempting to append an invalid type
```

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BaseList.append()` function receives an argument with the right *type*; however, the argument has an inappropriate *value*.  In Python, the `derived` initializer is not initializing the `sandbox.Base` part of its hierarchy.  This results in the Boost.Python object not containing a C++ `BaseWrap` object.  Hence, when `BaseList.append()` attempts to extract the C++ `BaseWrap` object, it fails and throws an error.

```python
class derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "test"
        # Base is not initialized.
    def f(self):
        print("Hello Derived!")

d = derived()
d.f() # `derived.f()` is resolved through Python's method-resolution-order.  
      # It is not invoking `BaseWrap::f()`.

a = A()
a.baseList.append(d) # d does not contain a BaseWrap object, so this throws.
```

To resolve the issue, explicitly invoke `Base.__init__()` within `derived.__init__()`:

```python
class derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "test"
        Base.__init__(self)
```

However, attempting to do this will surface other problems with how `BaseWrap` is exposed:

- The `sandbox.Base` class must be constructible from Python, so the bindings cannot provide `boost::python::no_init` as its initializer specification.  Generally, one would only want to use `boost::python::no_init` when the C++ objects are being explicitly instantiated from C++ and passed to Python, such as via factory functions.
- When `T` is `BaseWrap`, a `HeldType` of `Base*` fails to meet the requirements of `HeldType`.  In particular, the `HeldType` either needs to be: `BaseWrap`, a class derived from `BaseWrap`, or a dereferenceable type for which `boost::python::pointee<Base*>::type` is `BaseWrap` or a class derived from `BaseWrap`.  See the [`class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) specification for requirement details.

These can be resolved by exposing the class as follows:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
python::class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Base", python::init<>())
  .def("f", python::pure_virtual(&Base::f))
  ;
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0356aa8e65f66097) passing an object that derives from a C++ exposed class to a C++ vector exposed via the `vector_indexing_suite`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>

struct base
{
  virtual ~base() {}
  virtual int perform() = 0;
};

struct base_wrap: base, boost::python::wrapper<base>
{
  int perform() { return int(this->get_override("perform")()) - 10; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<base_wrap, boost::noncopyable>("Base", python::init<>())
    .def("perform", python::pure_virtual(&base::perform))
    ;

  python::class_<std::vector<base*>>("BaseList")
    .def(python::vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<base*>>())
    ;

  python::def("do_perform", +[](base* object) {
    return object->perform();
  });
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> class derived(example.Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.name = "test"
...         example.Base.__init__(self)
...     def perform(self):
...         return 42
...       
>>> d = derived()
>>> base_list = example.BaseList()
>>> base_list.append(d)
>>> assert(len(base_list) == 1)
>>> assert(base_list[0].perform() == 42)
>>> assert(example.do_perform(base_list[0]) == 32)
```

With collections and pointers, there are often some caveats.  In this case:

- The `BaseList` object does not have shared ownership of objects to which its elements refer.  Be careful to guarantee that objects referenced by the container have a lifetime at least as long as the container itself.  In the above example, if object `d` is deleted, then invoking `base_list[0].perform()` can result in undefined behavior.
- One cannot iterate over the `base_list`, as the iterator's value will attempt to perform a `base*`-to-Python conversion, which does not exists.

---

The above example also demonstrates the difference in function dispatching.  If Python can directly invoke a method, it will do so using its own method-resolution mechanics.  Note how `base_list[0].perform()` and `example.do_perform(base_list[0])` return different values, as one gets dispatched through `base_wrap::perform()` which manipulates the result, and the other does not.

In the original code:

```python
class derived(sandbox.Base):
    ...
    def f(self):
        print("Hello Derived!")

d = derived()
d.f()
```

As Python is aware of `derived.f()`, invoking `d.f()` will not get dispatched through `BaseWrap::f()`.  If `BaseWrap::f()` had been invoked, it would have thrown because `derived.f()` returned `None`, which will fail to convert to an `int`:

```cpp
struct BaseWrap : Base, wrapper<Base> {
    int f() { return this->get_override("f")(); }
                        // ^~~ returns a boost::python::object, faling to 
                        //     extract `int` will throw. 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your very well explained answer. I wish I could upvote the answer more. I'm struggling with the "One cannot iterate over the base_list, as the iterator's value will attempt to perform a base*-to-Python conversion, which does not exists." part now. But the rest works perfectly.

Comment: @user3035260  When iterating over a `BaseList` object, Python cannot safely assume that all `base*` are instances of `base_wrap`. Consider the case where a C++ type `foo` derives from `base` and a pointer to a `foo` instance gets pushed into the `std::vector<base*>` that is held within a Python object.  For more details about the `vector_indexing_suite`, consider reading this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32633277/1053968).